# How to save/restore data from an array - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, save

I have created an array. I want to be able to save it and have it load when the app is closed from memory. . I did some research and found you can use use these commands: SaveArrayListToSD and ReadArrayListFromSD.

However, I don't know how to relate these to the rest of my code...
How do I save and load the array when the app is opened/closed?

After further research, I have changed my mind about the SQLite database - I don't mind using it if it's easier. If I was to use an SQLite database, how would I go about saving my arraylist into the database?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //Rendering the UI
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);



    //Creating Array of Strings

    final ArrayList todoItems = new ArrayList();
    final ArrayAdapter aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            todoItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);


    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
        todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
        });
        }

    public static void SaveArrayListToSD(Context mContext, String savedArray, ArrayList todoItems) {

        try {

        FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(savedArray + ".dat", mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(todoItems);
            fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static Object ReadArrayListFromSD(Context mContext,String savedArray){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput(savedArray + ".dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object obj= (Object) ois.readObject();
            fis.close();
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use internal storage to save the strings in you ArrayList.  [Here is more info on using internal storage.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)  You can write the data in onStop or onDestory and read the data in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can write you simple example for you.

initialise SQLite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = db=openOrCreateDatabase("yourDBName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee(id VARCHAR,name VARCHAR,email VARCHAR);");

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+idField.getText()+"','"+nameTextfield.getText()+"','"+emailtextfield.getText()+"');");

db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Employee WHERE id='"+idField.getText()+"'");

db.execSQL("UPDATE Employee SET name='"+nameTextfield.getText()+"',email='"+emailTextfield.getText()+"'WHERE id='"+idField.getText()+"'");
```

And to Select from database please follow this

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE id='"+idField.getText()+"'", null);
if(c.moveToFirst()){
  //String id = c.getString(0);
  String name = c.getString(1);
  String email = c.getString(2);
}
```